# Roundcube, Postfix and SMTP authentication (CRAM-MD5) error

Tags: postfix, sasl, smtp-auth, roundcube

I'm having trouble configuring Roundcube with SMTP authentification on Postfix. All the credentials are true, because I have no problem using the e-mail from Thunderbird and my mobile phone e-mail client.
Here is the SMTP configuration for Roundcube:

```
$rcmail_config['smtp_server'] = 'tls://mx.cyssea.com';
$rcmail_config['smtp_port'] = 587;
$rcmail_config['smtp_user'] = '%u';
$rcmail_config['smtp_pass'] = '%p';
$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_type'] = '';
$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_cid'] = null;
$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_pw'] = null;
$rcmail_config['smtp_helo_host'] = '';
$rcmail_config['smtp_timeout'] = 0;
```

When I try to send an email from roundcube, I get the following error:

```
[12-Jul-2012 16:33:35 +0300]: SMTP Error: SMTP error: Authentication failure: No supported authentication methods (Code: ) in /usr/share/roundcube/program/include/main.inc on line 1745 (POST /roundcube/?_unlock=loading1342100016360&_lang=en?_task=mail&_action=send)
```

Even though the SASL authentification module for PHP is installed.

The communication between the mail server and Roundcube goes like this:

```
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 220 mx.cyssea.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu) 
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Send: EHLO 192.168.12.18
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-mx.cyssea.com 
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-PIPELINING
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-SIZE 10240000
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-ETRN
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-STARTTLS
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-AUTH CRAM-MD5
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-8BITMIME
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250 DSN
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Send: STARTTLS
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Send: EHLO 192.168.12.18
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-mx.cyssea.com
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-PIPELINING
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-SIZE 10240000
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-ETRN
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-AUTH CRAM-MD5
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250-8BITMIME
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250 DSN
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Send: RSET
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 250 2.0.0 Ok
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Send: QUIT
[12-Jul-2012 20:00:47 +0300]: Recv: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

I couldn't find any information regarding such errors with SMTP authentication on Google. Does anyone know what is the reason for such a strange behaviour?

Comment: Could you please provide version of roundcube that you are using ?

Comment: It's the Ubuntu Server 12.04 package. Package manager says it's 0.7.1

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your Roundcube installation doesn't support CRAM-MD5, which is the only mechanism offered by Postfix. I would probably just enable the PLAIN and LOGIN mechanisms and use those. You probably have a line like this in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
```

Change this to read:

```
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```